# Крышной или крышный вентилятор дымоудаления

Tags: орфография

крышной или крышный вентилятор дымоудаления как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Общелитературное - крышный -синонимы - крышевый, крышечный

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/68147/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9
http://www.icevent.ru/tovar/1123.htm

Профессионализм - крышной ,употребляется в технических текстах и в профессиональном общении. Так что оба произношения правильны:http://www.gramma.ru/ARRM/?RG1=6&RG2=all&flag=1&page=3

Answer (score 1):

Здесь надо руководствоваться даже не правилами русского языка, а ГОСТ, который вводит термин. По ГОСТ 22270-2018 вентилятор крышный.

Comment: Здесь надо? Где оно, это здесь?

Answer (score 0):

Есть технический термин КРЫШНОЙ, и в вашем случае он вполне применим.

Крышно́й (тех.)
Яндекс.Словари › Орфографический словарь. — 2004

Кры́шный (от кры́ша)
Яндекс.Словари › Орфографический словарь. — 2004